# disable click link on touch devices not working as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

**what I'm trying to do**
I have dropdown-menus that open on hover and the parent menus have their own landing page link. we're not willing to sacrifice this behavior, but if obviously creates problem for large touch enabled devices. So, I'm detecting touch devices with jquery, and disabling the parent menu click on devices larger than 990px wide. devices below 990px is considered as mobile view and it switches to toggle. This switch between the toggle and the desktop view is expected to continue on screen rotation too.

**what is happening**
the menu link is disabled on first load and works as expected. Then I rotate the screen (from landscape to portrait) and see the mobile menu as expected and navigate to another page. once the page loads, I rotate it again (from portrait to landscape) and the desktop view is visible, but the parent links are clickable now!

I want to prevent this click event on second rotation too. HTML is standard bootstrap 3 navigation code and my js is like this:

```
 function isTouchDevice() {

        return true == ("ontouchstart" in window || window.DocumentTouch && document instanceof DocumentTouch);
    }

$(document).ready(function () {

        $(window).resize(function () {
            var o = $(window).innerWidth();
            function isTouchDevice() {
                return true == ("ontouchstart" in window || window.DocumentTouch && document instanceof DocumentTouch);
            }
            if ((isTouchDevice() === true) && (o >= 990)) {

                $('.navbar .dropdown > a ').each(function () {
                    $(this).on("click", function(){
                        return false
                    })
                })
                alert('oi!!')
            }
            else {
                $('.navbar .dropdown > a ').each(function () {
                    $(this).on("click", function(){
                        location.href = this.href;
                    })
                });
                alert ("bad!") //for debugging purpose, not really needed
            }

        }).resize();


        //the mobile menu clicks events
        $('#menu .dropdown > a ').click(function () {
            location.href = this.href;
        });
    });
```

**PS** this is a website, not an android app. I have found answers that answer this type of questions for android apps.

**Update** the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Snowbell92/b26u6vgx/) for my code

Comment: Could you replicate similar demo in **Snippet** or [JSFiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: not sure if you can simulate touch on jsfiddle, but link coming up in a bit.

Comment: added jsfiddle link in the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it myself. Turns out, the condition for width checking was creating the problem and in my case, unnecessary, because bootstrap is already hiding the menu in smaller screens and I was targeting touch enabled desktop devices anyway. so I took off `&& (o >= 990)` from the `if` condition and it is working as expected.

full js is below (in case anyone needs it). I used the timer to prevent the event from firing before the resize, but it will probably work without the timer too. :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        var resizeTimer;
        $(window).on('resize', function(e){
            clearTimeout(resizeTimer);
            resizeTimer = setTimeout(function () {
                function isTouchDevice() {
                    return true == ("ontouchstart" in window || window.DocumentTouch && document instanceof DocumentTouch);
                }
                if (isTouchDevice() === true) {
                    $('.navbar .dropdown > a ').click(function () {
                        return false
                    });
                    console.log("landscape")
                }
                else {
                    $('.navbar .dropdown > a ').each(function () {
                        $(this).on("click", function(){
                            location.href = this.href;
                        })
                    });
                    console.log("portrait")
                }
            }, 250)
        }).trigger('resize');
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a problem with the way you are recognizing the mobile device. For checking device sizes I would not suggest using `$(window).innerWidth()`. What you are doing now does not check the screen size, rather it checks the window size, which fluctuates when switching orientation.

I would like to suggest that instead of checking for only >900px, that you check for the entire area of the device (width x height) so landscape and portrait would act the same way. And I would like to suggest using `screen.availHeight * screen.availWidth` to determine this.

I really hope this helps you with your problem. Please let me know if not and I'll help you debug.

Comment: let me test your suggestion and I'm getting back to you.

Comment: so I tried with `screen.availWidth` and the problem is still there. I think it is not initializing on rotation/ orientation change.

Comment: I think I have a better idea on the problem. on every rotation, both of the alerts fire, which means, at least one alert is firing twice. seems like both my conditions are becoming true at once. I still have no clue how to solve it though.